# Is there timezone offset bug in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I'm in Korea.

Rails version is 2.3.5

in my environment,

```
  config.time_zone = 'Seoul'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Seoul'
```

created_at and updated_at value is inserted with local time in database.

but, when I access model.created_at or model.updated_at, 
the value is understanding with UTC +9:00

So, I insert model to database and get the value, and check difference both values immediately,
It is different bellow:

```
>> Time.now.to_datetime
=> Sun, 24 Jan 2010 21:28:03 +0900
# insert new Product. And check difference Time.now and Product.created_at immediately.
>> Product.last.created_at.to_datetime
=> Mon, 25 Jan 2010 06:12:51 +0900
```

Is it a bug of rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known bug in Rails:

Rails Timezone Gotcha: ActiveRecord::Base.find does not convert Time objects to UTC

http://marklunds.com/articles/one/402